# How i get the button clicked time with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, timing

I would like to show my customer's the average registration time in seconds on the registration page. The average time will be based on last 15 registrations by using the cookies.

Here is sample text that i want use on my registration page:

> Registration will take about **3.1 seconds**. The is the average of
>   last 15 registrations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: this may be helpful ---------> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211414/page-load-time-with-jquery

Comment: OP needs not page loading time.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure? Cookies are placed on the customers computers and you will not be able to gether last 15 registrations to provide such statistics to the user.

You need to check the time in scope of one session from the loading registration page by GET request till the posting the registrations data using the POST request. And it's need to be done on the server side.

Something like this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static DateTime registrationStart;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            registrationStart = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    protected void Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan registrationTimeSpan = DateTime.Now - registrationStart;

        this.StoreRegistrationTime(registrationTimeSpan); // store registration date to DB
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping track of the time on the client side will be more accurate than keeping track of time on the server side for the mere fact that keeping track of time on the server side does not account for bandwidth latency or load times. If a user has a slow connection, a mobile connection or is accessing the site from another country this could seriously affect the outcome of timing if strictly kept track of on the server side.

In the click event for the button just set the time of the click as . . .

```
$('button.register').click(function(evt) {
    window.myApp.startTime = new Date().getTime(); //Milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970
});
```

If you are submitting your user input to register via ajax on the success of the call you can set another time (`window.myApp.endTime`) as with the click event then find the difference of the 2 times in Milliseconds to get the precision you are looking for.

window.myApp.registrationTime = window.myApp.endTime - window.myApp.startTime

`window.myApp.registrationTime` would need to be sent back to the server, as mentioned only the server will be able to keep track of the last 15 registrations in the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned, you can't really use cookies as they are stored on the user's machine, not the server. What you could do is get the time when the `ready` event fires, and then get the time when the form is submitted:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    $("#yourForm").submit(function() {
       var endTime = (new Date()).getTime(),
           totalTime = endTime - startTime;
    });
});
```

You could then store the time taken in a hidden `input` and submit it along with your form. Store the time in the database along with the user registration data, and simply query the database for the average of the last 15 registrations to get the data you want.