# Is there a way to put the number of seconds a script takes to execute (or "page load time") in the middle of the page?

Tags: php

I want to put the number of seconds a search script takes to search in PHP. But, I don't want to put that number at the bottom of the page. I put this at the top of the PHP file:

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
```

And then I put this where I am echoing out the number:

```
$time_end = microtime(true);
echo number_format($time_end - $time_start, 5);
```

The problem is that this doesn't count the whole script as there's still a lot of other code under that. Is there a way to determine how long it takes to execute but echo it in another place on the page rather than the bottom?

Comment: Do you want to present it at the top of a web page (which I guess could be done with css), or do you want it to be the first line on STDOUT from php (which would require some kind of buffering)?

Comment: Try the javascript/jquery solutions proposed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211414/page-load-time-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three possibilities:

- Echo the value inside a Javascript at the bottom of the page. The script can modify the DOM as soon as the page is loaded, so the value can be inserted anywhere in the document. Disadvantage: won't work for clients that don't support or ignore Javascript.
- Cheat and stop the timer early. You'll have to do all time-intensive stuff before the point in the document where you want the time (i.e. preload all results it in memory and echo it afterwards), so the part that you're not measuring is negligible. Disadvantage: it's not completely accurate and the pre-loading could be a hassle or memory-inefficient.
- Buffer all output with [output control functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) and perform a search-and-replace on the output buffer contents at the end of the script. Disadvantage: could be inefficient depending on your situation.

Comment: Hadn't thought of the top one, but that seems like a nice solution!

Comment: The first one is a great idea. Also, this search is part of a web application so people without JavaScript can't use it anyway. I'll go with the first solution, it seems like the best way to do it out of the three.

Answer (score 0):

Not precisely, but you can get a very close approximation by using [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php):

```
<?php

$time_start = microtime(true);

ob_start();
// Do stuff here
$page = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$time_end = microtime(true);
$elapsed = number_format($time_end - $time_start, 5);

var_dump($page, $elapsed);

?>
```