# Ideas on page load time measurements

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

The question is - how do you measure the time of page load, which technics you use, which recomendations can you give, and what positive and negative experience do you have.

The trouble is that even light pages in jsf can take up to 10 seconds to load. These pages don't require any evaluations, resources on rendering, etc. The obvious answer - it is in the queue on rendering... Ok, but may be something else?

Seems, it is needed to measure time starting from the request, including rendering, evaluations, data transfer time, client-side rendering time, etc.

Do you have any well working ways, tool chains, tools for a full lifetime trace of time of the page in JSF?

Glassfish-3, JSF-2 is used. Machine with 64 CPUs.

Comment: 10 seconds seems very long, you could take a look at JSF lifecycle as a start point : http://balusc.blogspot.ca/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie, how do you think (or may be you know), is there support from JSF framework for time tracking? 10 seconds - because shown pages need info from databases, and can be megabytes of size. This is special-purpose service.

Comment: Sorry I don't know any tool or library that can track you stats of generation time for pages. To do so, you need to create a PhaseListener and log datetime with URL. After that you will be able to track inside the data.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie, thank you - good advice! I appreciate it. You can post it as a separate answer with a link on the post. A can vote it up, while waiting any other ideas...

Comment: I'll take a couple of minutes and post some code of the idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple custom solution I've just made and tested. It provides some statistics on execution and rendering time. Of course all informations are only from serverside processing.

**Result example :**

```
Date                     ID request  URL                                  Phase              Execution time
2013-05-16 21:10:29.781  34          http://localhost:8080/web/page.jspx  RESTORE_VIEW 1     15
2013-05-16 21:10:29.796  34          http://localhost:8080/web/page.jspx  RENDER_RESPONSE 6  4438
2013-05-16 21:10:39.437  35          http://localhost:8080/web/page.jspx  RESTORE_VIEW 1     16
2013-05-16 21:10:39.453  35          http://localhost:8080/web/page.jspx  RENDER_RESPONSE 6  3937
```

The implementation is pretty straigth forward. First you have ton configure a **PhaseListener** inside `faces-config.xml`

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.spectotechnologies.jsf.phaselisteners.PhaseProcessesAnalyserListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

Here is **helper class** that keep information on each processing :

```
package com.spectotechnologies.website.common.helper;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;

/**
 *
 * @author Alexandre Lavoie
 */
public class PhaseProcess
{
    private int m_nIDRequest;
    private String m_sURL;
    private Date m_oStart;
    private Date m_oEnd;
    private PhaseId m_oPhase;

    public void setIdRequest(int p_nIDRequest)
    {
        m_nIDRequest = p_nIDRequest;
    }

    public int getIdRequest()
    {
        return m_nIDRequest;
    }

    public void setUrl(String p_sURL)
    {
        m_sURL = p_sURL;
    }

    public String getUrl()
    {
        return m_sURL;
    }

    public void setStart(Date p_oStart)
    {
        m_oStart = p_oStart;
    }

    public Date getStart()
    {
        return m_oStart;
    }

    public void setEnd(Date p_oEnd)
    {
        m_oEnd = p_oEnd;
    }

    public Date getEnd()
    {
        return m_oEnd;
    }

    public void setPhase(PhaseId p_oPhase)
    {
        m_oPhase = p_oPhase;
    }

    public PhaseId getPhase()
    {
        return m_oPhase;
    }

    public long getExecutionTime()
    {
        long lExecutionTime = -1;

        if(getEnd() != null)
        {
            lExecutionTime = getEnd().getTime() - getStart().getTime();
        }

        return lExecutionTime;
    }
}
```

Here is the class with the **business logic**, note that for the moment the stats will only grow and it is never deleted, could be a nice update to keep only last hour for example :

```
package com.spectotechnologies.website.common.helper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;

/**
 *
 * @author Alexandre Lavoie
 */
public class PhaseProcesses
{
    private List<PhaseProcess> m_lItems = new ArrayList();
    private int m_nNextIDRequest = 0;

    public static PhaseProcesses getInstance()
    {
        FacesContext oFaces = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        PhaseProcesses oPhaseProcesses = (PhaseProcesses)oFaces.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("sessionPhaseProcesses");

        if(oPhaseProcesses == null)
        {
            oPhaseProcesses = new PhaseProcesses();

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("sessionPhaseProcesses",oPhaseProcesses);
        }

        return oPhaseProcesses;
    }

    public void set(int p_nIDRequest, String p_sURL, PhaseId p_oPhase, int p_nType)
    {
        PhaseProcess oPhaseProcess;

        // Phase start
        switch(p_nType)
        {
            case 0:
                // start
                oPhaseProcess = new PhaseProcess();

                oPhaseProcess.setIdRequest(p_nIDRequest);
                oPhaseProcess.setUrl(p_sURL);
                oPhaseProcess.setPhase(p_oPhase);
                oPhaseProcess.setStart(new Date());

                if(m_lItems.size() > 250)
            {
                m_lItems.remove(0);
            }

                m_lItems.add(oPhaseProcess);
                break;
            case 1:
                // end
                for(int nPhase = m_lItems.size() - 1;nPhase >= 0;nPhase--)
                {
                    if(m_lItems.get(nPhase).getIdRequest() == p_nIDRequest && m_lItems.get(nPhase).getPhase() == p_oPhase)
                    {
                        m_lItems.get(nPhase).setEnd(new Date());
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public List<PhaseProcess> getList()
    {
        return m_lItems;
    }

    public Integer getNextIDRequest()
    {
        return m_nNextIDRequest++;
    }
}
```

Here is the famous **PhaseListener**, where informations are tracked :

```
package com.spectotechnologies.jsf.phaselisteners;

import com.spectotechnologies.website.common.helper.PhaseProcesses;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

/**
 *
 * @author Alexandre Lavoie
 */
public class PhaseProcessesAnalyserListener implements PhaseListener
{
    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId()
    {
        return PhaseId.ANY_PHASE;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent p_oEvent)
    {
        PhaseProcesses.getInstance().set(getIDRequest(),getURL(),p_oEvent.getPhaseId(),0);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent p_oEvent)
    {
        PhaseProcesses.getInstance().set(getIDRequest(),getURL(),p_oEvent.getPhaseId(),1);
    }

    private Integer getIDRequest()
    {
        Integer iIDRequest = (Integer)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("idrequest");

        if(iIDRequest == null)
        {
            iIDRequest = PhaseProcesses.getInstance().getNextIDRequest();

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("idrequest",iIDRequest);
        }

        return iIDRequest;
    }

    private String getURL()
    {
        Enumeration<String> lParameters;
        String sParameter;
        StringBuilder sbURL = new StringBuilder();
        Object oRequest = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

        try
        {
            if(oRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest)
            {
                sbURL.append(((HttpServletRequest)oRequest).getRequestURL().toString());

                lParameters = ((HttpServletRequest)oRequest).getParameterNames();

                if(lParameters.hasMoreElements())
                {
                    if(!sbURL.toString().contains("?"))
                    {
                        sbURL.append("?");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sbURL.append("&");
                    }
                }

                while(lParameters.hasMoreElements())
                {
                    sParameter = lParameters.nextElement();

                    sbURL.append(sParameter);
                    sbURL.append("=");
                    sbURL.append(URLEncoder.encode(((HttpServletRequest)oRequest).getParameter(sParameter),"UTF-8"));

                    if(lParameters.hasMoreElements())
                    {
                        sbURL.append("&");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // Do nothing
        }

        return sbURL.toString();
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the simple page I created to show statistics. A good improvement could be to add averages on pages processing, a per-idrequest processing time also.

**Bean code :**

```
package com.spectotechnologies.website.common.beans;

import com.spectotechnologies.website.common.helper.PhaseProcess;
import com.spectotechnologies.website.common.helper.PhaseProcesses;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author Alexandre Lavoie
 */
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class PagesStatisticsActions
{
    public List<PhaseProcess> getList()
    {
        return PhaseProcesses.getInstance().getList();
    }
}
```

**View code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <f:view contentType="application/xhtml+xml">
        <h:head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml;charset=UTF-8" />
        </h:head>

        <h:body>
            <h:dataTable value="#{pagesStatisticsActions.list}" var="item">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Date
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputText value="#{item.start}">
                        <f:convertDateTime timeZone="America/Montreal" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        ID request
                    </f:facet>

                    #{item.idRequest}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        URL
                    </f:facet>

                    #{item.url}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Phase
                    </f:facet>

                    #{item.phase}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Execution time (ms)
                    </f:facet>

                    #{item.executionTime}
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 1 :**

- Added parameters in URL
- Added a limitation of 250 logs

Comment: Seems for me, that full toolchain can be built in a such way : instead of time measurements put in context, we can implement some service, which will accept some kind of datagrams (easy messages), which will accept notifications like {place of execution, ID}. And if we add notification from a client side : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211414/page-load-time-with-jquery, if network is not busy, we can estimate, where content is processed (in data side, or on client side, etc). Am I correct?

Comment: Yes that would be very nice, if at the end of the jQuery calculation you can post back the value to a servlet for example, with a PhaseID = Client Rendering or something like that.

Comment: At least, even if time of massage passing through the network could be not little, but it case of long-durative page loading, time of easy-message passing can be uncomparably less than time of processing inside the long phase, so that we can easily detect long phase.

Comment: Sure, could only be interresting for long client-side rendering and/or long client-side loading (multiple files)

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is based on the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598728/ideas-on-page-load-time-measurements#16600008) posted by [Alexandre Lavoie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354831/alexandre-lavoie), but is applicable for ADF Faces:

**PhaseProcessingTimeAnalyserListener**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Map;
 
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 
import oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PagePhaseEvent;
import oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PagePhaseListener;
import oracle.adf.share.ADFContext;
 
import com.mhis.posm.web.lifecycle.helper.PhaseProcessor;
 
/**
 * Class PhaseProcessingTimeAnalyserListener calculates the execution time of each Phase of ADF
 * @author TapasB
 */
public class PhaseProcessingTimeAnalyserListener implements PagePhaseListener, Serializable {
 
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 6814928970314659328L;
 
 /**
  * Method beforePhase notifies the listener before the execution of a specific phase of the ADF Page Lifecycle.
  * @author TapasB
  * @param phaseEvent
  * @see oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PagePhaseListener#beforePhase(oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PagePhaseEvent)
  */
 @Override
 public void beforePhase(PagePhaseEvent phaseEvent) {
  int phaseId = phaseEvent.getPhaseId();
  String phaseName = Lifecycle.getPhaseName(phaseId);
  PhaseProcessor.getInstance().process(getRequestId(), getURL(), phaseId, phaseName, PhaseProcessor.PhaseType.BEGIN);
 }
 
 /**
  * Method afterPhase notifies the listener after the execution of a specific phase of the ADF Page Lifecycle.
  * @author TapasB
  * @param phaseEvent
  * @see oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PagePhaseListener#afterPhase(oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PagePhaseEvent)
  */
 @Override
 public void afterPhase(PagePhaseEvent phaseEvent) {
  int phaseId = phaseEvent.getPhaseId();
  String phaseName = Lifecycle.getPhaseName(phaseId);
  PhaseProcessor.getInstance().process(getRequestId(), getURL(), phaseId, phaseName, PhaseProcessor.PhaseType.END);
 }
 
 /**
  * Method getRequestId generates and returns an unique ID value for each Request
  * @author TapasB
  * @return requestId
  */
 private Integer getRequestId() {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  Map<String, Object> requestScope = ADFContext.getCurrent().getRequestScope();
  Integer requestId = (Integer) requestScope.get("requestId");
 
  if (requestId == null) {
   requestId = PhaseProcessor.getInstance().getNextRequestId();
   requestScope.put("requestId", requestId);
  }
 
  return requestId;
 }
 
 /**
  * Method getURL returns the URL in which the application is requested
  * @author TapasB
  * @return a String URL
  */
 private String getURL() {
  Enumeration<String> parameterNames = null;
  String parameterName = null;
  StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  Object request = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
 
  try {
   if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    urlBuilder.append(servletRequest.getRequestURL().toString());
    parameterNames = servletRequest.getParameterNames();
 
    if (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
     if (!urlBuilder.toString().contains("?")) {
      urlBuilder.append("?");
     } else {
      urlBuilder.append("&");
     }
    }
 
    while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
     parameterName = parameterNames.nextElement();
 
     urlBuilder.append(parameterName);
     urlBuilder.append("=");
     urlBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(servletRequest.getParameter(parameterName), "UTF-8"));
 
     if (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
      urlBuilder.append("&");
     }
    }
   }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
  }
 
  return urlBuilder.toString();
 }
}
```

**PhaseProcessor**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
 
import oracle.adf.share.ADFContext;
 
import com.edifixio.osrd.generic.log.Log;
 
/**
 * Class PhaseProcessor processes the Phase execution time
 * @author TapasB
 */
public class PhaseProcessor implements Serializable {
 
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 6658181867505616109L;
 
 private List<Phase> phases = new ArrayList<Phase>();
 private AtomicInteger nextRequestId = new AtomicInteger(1);
 
 /**
  * Constructor PhaseProcessor is private
  * @author TapasB
  */
 private PhaseProcessor() {
 
 }
 
 /**
  * Class PhaseType
  * @author TapasB
  */
 public static enum PhaseType {
  BEGIN,
  END;
 }
 
 /**
  * Method getInstance returns a Session Instance of this class 
  * @author TapasB
  * @return an PhaseProcessor instance
  */
 public static PhaseProcessor getInstance() {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  Map<String, Object> sessionScope = ADFContext.getCurrent().getSessionScope();
  PhaseProcessor phaseProcessor = (PhaseProcessor) sessionScope.get("phases");
 
  if (phaseProcessor == null) {
   phaseProcessor = new PhaseProcessor();
   sessionScope.put("phases", phaseProcessor);
  }
 
  return phaseProcessor;
 }
 
 /**
  * Method process processes the {@link Phase} 
  * @author TapasB
  * @param requestId - the unique ID for each request
  * @param url - the url in which the application is requested
  * @param phaseId - ADF's Phase ID
  * @param phaseName - ADF's Phase Name
  * @param phaseType - BEGIN or END
  */
 public void process(int requestId, String url, int phaseId, String phaseName, PhaseType phaseType) {
  Phase phase;
 
  switch (phaseType) {
   case BEGIN:
    phase = new Phase();
 
    phase.setRequestId(requestId);
    phase.setUrl(url);
    phase.setPhaseId(phaseId);
    phase.setPhaseName(phaseName);
    phase.setStartTime(new Date());
 
    phases.add(phase);
 
    Log.info(this, "The Phase: " + phase.getPhaseName(phaseId) + " begins. Requested URL: " + phase.getUrl());
    break;
 
   case END:
    ListIterator<Phase> phaseIterator = phases.listIterator(phases.size());
 
    while (phaseIterator.hasPrevious()) {
     phase = phaseIterator.previous();
 
     if (phase.getRequestId() == requestId && phase.getPhaseId() == phaseId && phase.getPhaseName().equals(phaseName)) {
      phase.setEndTime(new Date());
      Log.info(this, "The Phase: " + phase.getPhaseName(phaseId) + " ends with execution time: '" + (phase.getEndTime().getTime() - phase.getStartTime().getTime()) + "' millisecondes. Requested URL: " + phase.getUrl());
      phaseIterator.remove();
      break;
     }
 
    }
 
    break;
  }
 }
 
 /**
  * Method getNextRequestId returns and increment the unique ID 
  * @author TapasB
  * @return the ID
  */
 public Integer getNextRequestId() {
  return nextRequestId.getAndIncrement();
 }
}
```

**Phase**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
 
import oracle.adf.controller.faces.lifecycle.JSFLifecycle;
 
/**
 * Class Phase represent a phase
 * @author TapasB
 */
public class Phase implements Serializable {
 
 private static final long serialVersionUID = -461595462579265128L;
 
 private int requestId;
 private String url;
 private Date startTime;
 private Date endTime;
 private int phaseId;
 private String phaseName;
 
 /**
  * Constructor Phase is default
  * @author TapasB
  */
 public Phase() {
 
 }
 
 /**
  * Method getRequestId returns requestId
  * @author TapasB
  * @return requestId
  */
 public int getRequestId() {
  return requestId;
 }
 
 /**
  * Method setRequestId sets the requestId
  * @author TapasB
  * @param requestId the requestId to set
  */
 public void setRequestId(int requestId) {
  this.requestId = requestId;
 }
 
 /**
  * Method getUrl returns url
  * @author TapasB
  * @return url
  */
 public String getUrl() {
  return url;
 }
 
 /**
  * Method setUrl sets the url
  * @author TapasB
  * @param url the url to set
  */
 public void setUrl(String url) {
  this.url = url;
 }
 
 /**
  * Method getStartTime returns startTime
  * @author TapasB
  * @return startTime
  */
 public Date getStartTime() {
  return startTime;
 }
 
 /**
  * Method setStartTime sets the startTime
  * @author TapasB
  * @param startTime the startTime to set
  */
 public void setStartTime(Date startTime) {
  this.startTime = startTime;
 }
 
 /**
  * Method getEndTime returns endTime
  * @author TapasB
  * @return endTime
  */
 public Date getEndTime() {
  return endTime;
 }
 
 /**
  * Method setEndTime sets the endTime
  * @author TapasB
  * @param endTime the endTime to set
  */
 public void setEndTime(Date endTime) {
  this.endTime = endTime;
 }
 
 /**
  * Method getPhaseId returns phaseId
  * @author TapasB
  * @return phaseId
  */
 public int getPhaseId() {
  return phaseId;
 }
 
 /**
  * Method setPhaseId sets the phaseId
  * @author TapasB
  * @param phaseId the phaseId to set
  */
 public void setPhaseId(int phaseId) {
  this.phaseId = phaseId;
 }
 
 /**
  * Method getPhaseName returns phaseName
  * @author TapasB
  * @return phaseName
  */
 public String getPhaseName() {
  return phaseName;
 }
 
 /**
  * Method setPhaseName sets the phaseName
  * @author TapasB
  * @param phaseName the phaseName to set
  */
 public void setPhaseName(String phaseName) {
  this.phaseName = phaseName;
 }
 
 /**
  * Method getPhaseName returns the name of the Phase
  * @author TapasB
  * @param phaseId
  * @return the phase name
  */
 public String getPhaseName(int phaseId) {
  if (phaseId == JSFLifecycle.INIT_CONTEXT_ID) {
   return "INIT_CONTEXT";
  } else if (phaseId == JSFLifecycle.PREPARE_MODEL_ID) {
   return "PREPARE_MODEL";
  } else if (phaseId == JSFLifecycle.APPLY_INPUT_VALUES_ID) {
   return "APPLY_INPUT_VALUES";
  } else if (phaseId == JSFLifecycle.VALIDATE_INPUT_VALUES_ID) {
   return "VALIDATE_INPUT_VALUES";
  } else if (phaseId == JSFLifecycle.PROCESS_UPDATE_MODEL_ID) {
   return "PROCESS_UPDATE_MODEL";
  } else if (phaseId == JSFLifecycle.VALIDATE_MODEL_UPDATES_ID) {
   return "VALIDATE_MODEL_UPDATES";
  } else if (phaseId == JSFLifecycle.PROCESS_COMPONENT_EVENTS_ID) {
   return "PROCESS_COMPONENT_EVENTS";
  } else if (phaseId == JSFLifecycle.METADATA_COMMIT_ID) {
   return "METADATA_COMMIT";
  } else if (phaseId == JSFLifecycle.PREPARE_RENDER_ID) {
   return "PREPARE_RENDER";
  } else if (phaseId == JSFLifecycle.JSF_RESTORE_VIEW_ID) {
   return "RESTORE_VIEW";
  } else if (phaseId == JSFLifecycle.JSF_APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES_ID) {
   return "JSF_APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES";
  } else if (phaseId == JSFLifecycle.JSF_PROCESS_VALIDATIONS_ID) {
   return "JSF_PROCESS_VALIDATIONS";
  } else if (phaseId == JSFLifecycle.JSF_UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES_ID) {
   return "JSF_UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES";
  } else if (phaseId == JSFLifecycle.JSF_INVOKE_APPLICATION_ID) {
   return "JSF_INVOKE_APPLICATION";
  } else {
   return "JSF_RENDER_RESPONSE";
  }
 }
}
```

For more information look [here](http://tapas-tanmoy-bose.blogspot.in/2014/01/measuring-execution-time-of-adf-faces.html).